# Динамическое заполнение TreeView с привязкой Binding

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте!
У меня такой вопрос:
Как сделать шаблон(стиль) отображения элемента TreeView с динамическим его заполнением с пособом привязки данных Binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Про шаблоны [вообще](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms745683.aspx).
Про шаблоны TreeView [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms752048.aspx).
Ну и несколько примеров [здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CustomTreeViewLayout.aspx) и [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/wpf/102105/).